# Apache, PHP multi thread over windows for concurrent users

Tags: php, windows, multithreading, apache, concurrency

I have a MS sql server that solves queries sent by a system made in PHP, everything under windows. the problem i have right now is that if a query takes a long time o proccess, all the remaining incoming request made by other users won't be processed until php get the results from the first one and finishes the first request.

is there a way to allow/make php to handle parallel, simultaneously many request? because right now i have a very big bottleneck since the sql server can handle a lot of simultaneous queries but the web application can  just send the block of queries request by request.

if neccesary i can use solutions based on linux too

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved my problem using the function session_write_close()
since the session file was the same for all the request and php was locking it, all the request get stucked